# How to pick between RabbitMQ and ZeroMQ or something else?

Tags: performance, message-queuing

I'm looking for a queuing system which is fast and reliable and potentially can be spread across machines.  Platform is Linux.  Open source is preferable.

Both RabbitMQ and ZeroMQ look good but I have no experience with these or any other queuing systems.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ both support an open messaging protocol called AMQP. The advantage to AMQP is that it’s designed to be a highly-robust and open alternative to the two commercial message queues out there (IBM and Tibco).

However, ZeroMQ doesn’t support message persistence across crashes reboots. That leaves us with RabbitMQ. (That being said if you don’t need persistence ZeroMQ is pretty darn interesting…incredibly low latency and flexible topologies).

Comment: Small correction, RabbitMQ is an AMQP implementation, ZeroMQ isn't. The history of this interesting :) http://lists.openamq.org/pipermail/openamq-dev/2010-March/001598.html

Comment: Not true that ZeroMQ doesn't support persistence. ZeroMQ is just a messaging library and you can easily write a broker that persists messages if you need that. ZeroMQ is more like a toolbox that you can use to build a custom messaging system, while AMQP is protocol that mandates a broker and specifies a lot of broker behaviors, like message persistence.

Comment: @MikeHadlow the history is actually much interesting, thanks for the link

Answer (score 12):

I did a very basic evaluation of ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, MSMQ and ActiveMQ a while back. http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/04/message-queue-shootout.html

Answer (score 5):

Detailed description is here. But please dont 100% rely on this. 3 things have 3 targets.

[Message queue evaluation notes](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Message_Queue_Evaluation_Notes)

For a transaction based real-time fast data dissemination is good with ZeroMQ.
High message reliability is best with RabbitMQ.
Intermideate solution is ActiveMQ

Answer (score 3):

We did an evaluation of various messaging approaches.

BoostASIO (sockets), ZeroMQ (lightweight framework) and OpenDDS (fully featured implementation of the OMG DDS spec.)

A paper describing the results can be found [here](http://mnb.ociweb.com/mnb/MiddlewareNewsBrief-201004.html). The results are not what you might expect.

**Disclosure: poster is CEO of company that did the evaluation, and company's product is included in evaluation.**

Comment: A director at a company posting a link to an evaluation performed by that company, which compares a product made by that company to other products.  This really feels more like an advertisement than an answer.  Especially when this is the only post/activity from the answer poster.